# proving a subset of a function is continuous given that the function is continuous

Tags: analysis

Prove that if $J \subseteq I$ and $f : I \to R$ is continuous at $c \in J$, then $f(J)$ is continuous at $c$.

Not sure where to begin, I am new to analysis.

Comment: What is your definition of "continuous"? Is it the pre-image of an open set is open, or is it the $\delta$-$\epsilon$ definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $j \colon J \rightarrow I$ be the inclusion map defined by
$$
j(x) := x \qquad \mbox{ for all } x \in J.
$$
Then the restriction $f| J \colon J \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the composite $f \circ j$.

So if we show that the inclusion map is continuous, then it will follow that $f | J$ is also continuous.

Now let $I$ be any topological space, and let $J$ have the subspace topology which $J$ inherits from $I$. Then, for any open set $V$ of $I$, we have
$$
j^{-1} (V) = V \cap J,
$$
which is open in the subspace $J$ of $I$, from which it follows that the inclusion map $j$ is continuous.

Alternatively, assuming that $I$ is a metric space with metric $d$. Then as $f$ is continuous at the point $c \in I$, so for every real number $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a real number $\delta = \delta(c, \varepsilon) > 0$ such that
$$
\big\lvert f(x) - f(c) \big\rvert < \varepsilon
$$
for any point $x \in I$ for which
$$
d(x, c) < \delta, \tag{1} 
$$
and thus in particular for any point $x \in J$ which satisfies (1). Thus it follows that $f | J$ is continuous at $c$.